# Error deploying Python package to AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

AWS Successfully creates the lambda function when I upload the zip file. But it's giving this error when I test it out.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'amazonSNS'"
}
```

Following are the contents of the zip file that I created. I tried changing the name of the zip file to "amazonSNS" to match the `amazonSNS.py` file, but no help, same issue.

[image]

The Lambda handler in the Configuration of the Lambda function is set to "amazonSNS.handler" where amazonSNS is the filename and handler is the function name that needs to be called, as they have instructed in the documentation.

Here are the contents of the python file

```
import boto3
import MySQLdb

client = boto3.client("sns")
rds = boto3.client("rds")

def handler(event, context):
    conn = MySQLdb.connect("host", "username", "password", "database")
    cur = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    query = "select * from login.login limit 10"
    cur.execute(query)
    print cur.fetchall()
    print conn
```

What might be the issue here?

Here is the Log output

> START RequestId: 76a61551-052a-11e6-b466-8fa0769ac309 Version: $LATEST
>   Unable to import module 'amazonSNS': No module named _mysql
>
> END RequestId: 76a61551-052a-11e6-b466-8fa0769ac309 REPORT RequestId:
>   76a61551-052a-11e6-b466-8fa0769ac309  Duration: 0.33 ms   Billed
>   Duration: 100 ms

**UPDATE**

I added a few more files from "site-package" folder that I thought was part of the MySQLdb package, Here are the current contents of the zip file.

[image]

And after this the new Log of the error is.

> START RequestId: c0715d9a-0531-11e6-9409-a3b194fd4afd Version: $LATEST
>   Unable to import module 'amazonSNS': libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> END RequestId: c0715d9a-0531-11e6-9409-a3b194fd4afd REPORT RequestId:
>   c0715d9a-0531-11e6-9409-a3b194fd4afd  Duration: 0.35 ms   Billed
>   Duration: 100 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 22 MB

Comment: I would **strongly** suggest always using virtual environments when developing lambda functions. [Tutorials](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) on usage are out there. This allows you to build and test your software with *exactly* the packages you need. Then, you can just copy the contents of `pip --version` (run with the virtualenv activated) into the top directory of your uploaded zip file, and make sure you're getting every (Python) file you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that getting all the *Python* files you need doesn't seem to cover your bases on some software that is dependent on the *system* files. @OmarZairi's answer shows you a work around that should be pretty universal when files that aren't in your virtualenv's `site-packages` directory are showing up in errors.

Comment: Just realized that using `pip --version` to identify the location of your virtualenv's `site-packages` directory might not work if you're not using Pipenv or virtualenvwrapper. You should probably use one of those anyway.

Comment: Here's [info on the virtualenv strategy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) from Amazon's (frankly, generally terrible) official documentation.

Comment: If you spend a bunch of time creating Lambda processes, it might be worthwhile to test them in a virtual environment created in the same environment as the lambda process, which can be done by creating an [EC2 instance using the official image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html).

Answer (score 5):

To solve this issue:
I searched for libmysqlclient.so.20 (the version number at the end may differ)

```
find /. -name "libmysqlclient.so.20"
```

My ouput was

```
/./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.20
```

I then copied that file into the root directory of my package

```
cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.20 <your package path>
```

Comment: `locate` will generally find that faster than find.

Comment: I wonder if the version number at the end is the problem. Your Python version probably references a version number that is different from the one available on Lambda instances.

Comment: Yeah the version number will differ based on your system's version. but i also noticed the dependency package must be ubuntu compatible (i'm assuming since AWS Lambda's run on linux based)

Answer (score 1):

I failed to compile `MySQL-python` in way to make it work in Lambda. Instead I switched to `pymysql`. I am not sure about performance, but at least this works.

P.S. I wonder why there is no official recommendations about suggested MySQL driver on amazon. At least I haven't found it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when using mysqlclient (the MySQLd fork which works on Python3).

Since I use [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) for easy deployment, the solution was simple: just switch to the original MySQLd package (which does not support Python 3, though): `pip install mysql-python` 
Zappa comes with a pre-compiled [version](https://github.com/Miserlou/lambda-packages) of it.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install MySQLdb?  http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html says:

> ImportError: No module named _mysql
>   If you see this, it's likely you did some wrong when installing MySQLdb; re-read (or read) README. _mysql is the low-level C module that interfaces with the MySQL client library.

Install MySQLdb with pip if you didn't already.

Comment: Yes, I installed MySQLdb using `pip install MySQL-python`. There was another dependency that I had to install on my Ubuntu machine using `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` after which MySQLdb installed successfully. Do you think the dependency might be an issue here? If so, then any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried using a different library like https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL?

Comment: No, because this(MySQLdb) seems to be the most popular and the fastest. But let me give another library a try.